# AppleScript - do shell python3 error module not found but installed

Tags: python, applescript

So I'm trying to run a python script. Which runs fine in the terminal but when I do it in the AppleScript it gives me an script error.

```
do shell script "cd /Users/me/Desktop/folder1; python testRun.py
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/folder1/run1.py", line 2, in <module>
    import myutils
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/folder1/run1.py", line 14, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests
```

- myutils - is my python script
- requests - is a python module

Doing a pip3 list it shows requests

```
requests               2.27.1
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Why is it working in the terminal but not in the AppleScript?

After adding the path

@simpleApp.  Thanks for the direction.  So doing which in terminal I got: python3

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.  using that path.
```

Script editor error:

```
  I did this do shell script ("export PATH=\"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:$PATH\";cd \"/Users/me/Desktop/folder1/";testRun.py")

Error output
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File \"/Users/me/Desktop/folder1/testRun.py\", line 41, in <module>
        driver = myutils.get_csv_report(dl_path, WEBREPORTS_URL, auth)
      File \"/Users/me/Desktop/folder1/myutils.py\", line 199, in get_csv_report
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, options=options)
      File \"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py\", line 164, in __init__
        self.service.start()
      File \"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py\", line 81, in start
        raise WebDriverException(
    selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Comment: need to check the environment in which the terminal and AppleScript have been executed. if you type `which python` and `which pip3` both in terminal and applescript, compare these paths.

Comment: And when you find that they're different, read [TN2065: do shell script in applescript](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html).

Comment: Yeah looks like the environment pip installs are different. Is there a way to use the same pip environment that is in the terminal. So you're not installing modules numerous times?

Comment: need to adjust the path, for example, `export PATH="/xx/xx/bin:$PATH"`, so pip3 and python come upfront on the PATH.

Comment: @simpleApp. Thanks for the direction. I updated the original post with the issues that I'm still having even after adding the the path.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: either paste `geckodriver` in a folder that is in the path or add a folder where you have `geckodriver` to the PATH. note :  command to see path is `echo $PATH`

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly a complex system with multiple user scripts:

- /Users/me/Desktop/folder1/testRun.py
- /Users/me/Desktop/folder1/myutils.py
- /Users/me/Desktop/folder1/run1.py
- etc...

In Terminal this will work because sub-shells will be created with Terminal's default shell, which invokes a well-developed PATH variable. AppleScript's `do shell script` invokes a stripped down PATH, and even if you import a more developed one at the top level, sub-shells will *still* invoke the stripped down PATH.

The best practice for dealing with this problem is to use full paths for every utility you invoke, except ones you *know* are in /usr/bin, /bin, /usr/sbin, or /sbin. And you have to do that in every script, not just the top level one. I mean, I suppose you could do this with export as well, but you'd have to dig into the secondary scripts to find out which paths you need to export anyways, so why not fix it at the source?

Comment: yeah I just ended up using UI scripting with the terminal to get this working.. thanks for the help though...